# Load resource from anywhere in classpath

Tags: java

I have a simple java application that loads a properties file from the current package.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("props.properties");
```

This works fine when the property file I want is in the current package. However, I want to package this application as a JAR and define and override with a new properties file where I use it. Is there a way to load the first resource named "props.properties" that is on the classpath?

I want it to be as easy to override the properties file via command line:

```
java.exe -classpath props.properties;myJar.jar com.test.MyApp
```

I don't want to have to unpack the JAR and modify the properties file to change something. I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all else fails you could use two different file names, say `props-default.properties` inside `myJar.jar` and `props.properties` to override on the command-line. In your code, you'd try loading the `props.properties` file first and fallback to `props-default.properties` if it wasn't found.

Answer (score 31):

The [javadoc for `Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) documents the lookup logic:

> If the name begins with a `'/'` (`'\u002f'`), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
>
> Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>        `modified_package_name/name`
>
> Where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for `'.'` (`'\u002e'`).

So in other words, the resource name passed to the method should look like `/com/package/p2/props.properties` if the `props.properties` is stored in the `com.package.p2` package instead of the current class's.

Answer (score 13):

I'm sure it's too late for the answer but it could be interesting for googlers
this small code snippet helpers to load a properties file from any where in the Classpath.

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    if (cl != null) {
        URL url = cl.getResource(CONF_PROPERTIES);
        if (url == null) {
            url = cl.getResource("/" + CONF_PROPERTIES);
        }
        if (url != null) {
            try {
                InputStream in = url.openStream();
                props = new Properties();
                props.load(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log the exception
            } finally {
               // close opened resources
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't use getResourceAsStream?

Comment: I use this kind of initialization as I'm developing a EE application.
During development, My application is aware of that file throw Eclipse Classpath. But at the creation of the EAR, the application is aware of that file throw the ClassPath configuration throw WebSphere.

I'll appreciate another elegant solution as well.

Comment: I see. I would not have expected this to throw different Exceptions (or at least would expect that they both have a common parent, like IOException). Interesting approach though.

Comment: I don't think this actually loads a properties file from anywhere in the Classpath; the documentation cited in matt b's answer says that it will load the file from either the current package or the root, but not from **anywhere** in the classpath.

Comment: It does not work for me in maven project, when the resource is in test folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe: `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`

EDIT:

I don't think this is significantly different to `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` from the question, since as mentioned you still have to get the ClassLoader you want to use to load the resource.

Since you provide the resource in the `-classpath` in your example, it should be available from the same class loader as your "main" class (in the SUN JVM, that's `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`, not sure if this can/does vary for other JVM implementations).

Comment: Sounds about right: You want to ask a ClassLoader that's the "boss" of the one that loaded your class, so it may have access to more packages. Another possibility is to try `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` - as the name implies, it's the "boss" of the others.

Comment: there is no static method `getResourceAsStream()` in the `ClassLoader` class.

Comment: and the system classloader will likely load resources from outside of your application's classpath, i.e. looking in the bootstrap directories in the JRE install path

Comment: correct, `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream()` is shorthand for `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`, which returns null for both `props.properties` and `/com/test/props.properties`

Comment: A hacky way would be to load it straight from the Application ClassLoader (which is responsible for "-classpath"): sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.getAppClassLoader(sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtClassLoader()).getResourceAsStream(...); probably not portable.