# Java - Getting file from same package

Tags: java, file, package

If I want to read from "Words.txt" which is in the same package as the class, how would I do this? Doing simply `Scanner = new Scanner(new File("Words.txt"));` returns an error.

Comment: Try putting the .txt file in the root of your project.  While text files can be in the same folder as files in a particular package, that doesn't really make them part of the package.  Instead, you need to load it from the file system (or alternatively, from the jar or war.)

Answer (score 18):

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("Words.txt");
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the text file is in the same directory as the `.class`, rather than the `.java` file you can do

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Words.txt"));
```

What you have will look for the file in the current working directory. When you are building your program this is typically the root directory of your program. When you run it as a standalone program it is usually the directory the program was started from.

Comment: I don't know if every answer is just based on another or the method name just changed but, it is `getClass().getResourceAsStream("Words.txt")`

Comment: @Winter based on my flaky memory I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner = new Scanner(new File("/path/to/Words.txt"));
```

The argument in the File() constructor, Is the path relative to the system your VM is running on, it s doesn't depend on the classe's package.

If you your words.txt is a resource packaged with your war you can see here : [Load resource from anywhere in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294196/load-resource-from-anywhere-in-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsInputStream("Words.txt"));

String s = new String();

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){


        s = s + scanner.nextLine();


 }
```

Comment: You meant `getClass().getResourceAsStream("Words.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions did not work for me, however this seemed to work as expected even when the source code is exported as a docker image.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;


public class FileUtil {
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FileUtil.class.getSimpleName());

private FileUtil() {
    // Private constructor
}

private static FileUtil instance = null;

public static FileUtil getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new FileUtil();
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Read file from the the resources folder as a string from an
 * {@link InputStream}
 * 
 * @param fileName: This can be name.txt or any file format of your choice
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public String getResourceFileAsString(String fileName) throws ValidationFailedException {
    try {
        fileName = String.format("classpath:%s", fileName);
        try (InputStream reader = new ClassPathResource(fileName).getInputStream()) {
            return IOUtils.toString(reader, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, String.format("Failed to read template {%s}", e.getMessage()), e);
        throw new Exception(String.format("Failed to read template {%s}", e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

}