# How can you load images easily in Intellij?

Tags: java, image, input, intellij-idea, assets

I'm trying to load images from my project directory.

I have images in a folder, starting at the project directory:

```
Project/res/textures
```

How might I easily access these images so I can say:

`"/textures/image.png"` when loading an image?

Answer (score 1):

You want `textures` to be in the root of your class path. An easy way to do that is to mark `Project/res` as a [Resources Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html#d1325429e137).

Comment: I believe I've tried this on my mac. I've made Project/res a Resource root and then try to access it and it won't work. Do I need to make textures a source root folder?

Comment: An image is not source, is it? Try using `textures/image.png` (without the leading slash). How are you loading the image? The easiest way is using [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String)), but you can also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294196/load-resource-from-anywhere-in-classpath).