# Adding JavaScript files to Maven classpath using Nashorn

Tags: javascript, maven, nashorn

I would like to add some JavaScript files in the `src/main/javascript` folder of my Maven project. I want to be able to run them using the Nashorn JavaScript engine embedded in Java 8.

I want to run some tests that are in the `src/test/javascript` against the source files.

Is it possible? Is there a plugin for that?

Comment: Can you use the default resource folders (src/main/resources and src/test/resources) of a Maven project?

Comment: @gclaussn yes I can use them

Answer (score 2):

Nashorn has "[load](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-load)" builtin JS function that can load a script from:

- File
- URL
- resources from classpath
- Nashorn's bundled builtin scripts like mozilla_compat.js, FX scripts

For your specific case, you can add your .js files as resources to your application jar and invoke

```
load("classpath:...")
```

from a Nashorn script. This loads using ClassLoader.getResource, ClassLoader.getSystemResource APIs automatically.

There is a github project called "[Nasven](https://github.com/nasven)" - Nasven.js is a server, desktop, and shell-script application runtime for apps written in Javascript possibly dependent on Maven artifacts

Answer (score 1):

You can specifiy additional resource directories by adding "build/resources/resource" tags in your pom.xml. Please have a look at following documentation:

[Specifying resource directories](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)

Another possibility is the usage of the [Build-Helper-Maven-Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html). It provides goals for adding [resources](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-resource-mojo.html) and [test resources](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-resource-mojo.html). Please refer on the usage documentation.

If you have added the resource directory, you should be able to load your java script [files from the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294196/load-resource-from-anywhere-in-classpath) and execute them with the script engine Nashorn.