# Not able to load file from Maven resources with Paths.get()

Tags: java, maven, java-8, filenotfoundexception, nosuchfileexception

I apologize for this seemingly easy and almost a stupid question, but I have spent a lot of time to fix it without much success.

I created a very simple maven project and then a simple text file inside the `src/resources` folder like this.

[image]

[image]

pom.xml is simple. The `App` class looks like this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt")).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

And the exception that I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: test.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2784)
    at java.nio.file.Files.lines(Files.java:3744)
    at java.nio.file.Files.lines(Files.java:3785)
    at com.rahul.App.main(App.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This seems to be a very stupid problem but I just can't get my head around it. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Use `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294196/load-resource-from-anywhere-in-classpath

Comment: I could...but whats wrong with this. It's supposed to be much more "simpler" with java 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using Maven and the text file that you want to load is correctly placed to be in the classpath : `src/main/resources`.  The problem is that  `Paths.get("test.txt")` doesn't search the file in the classpath but in the filesystem.

So what you need is getting the resource from the classpath as a URI and to pass it to `Paths.get(URI)`:

```
Path textFile = Paths.get(App.class.getResource("/test.txt").toURI());
Files.lines(textFile).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that the way to get the `Path` is really convoluted.
Unfortunately the `Class` class was not updated to take advantage of the java nio API that was introduced in Java 7.
It would be really simpler if we could write something like :

```
Files.lines(App.class.getResourcePath("/test.txt"))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: where is getClass() defined ?

Comment: `The problem is that  Paths.get("test.txt") doesn't search the file in the classpath but in the filesystem.` ==> wow...I had no clue about this.

Comment: `getClass()` is defined in the `Class` class. In your case, it is the `App` class.

Comment: You are welcome. I completely agree. It is really too much complex to make a so simple thing. I updated about.

Comment: Just try : App.class instead of getClass() if using in static method(inside main), getClass() is called on "this"/current object.

Comment: @Bikas Katwal Right. The actual code uses static context. I updated to be conform to. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ***test.txt*** path. You are trying to access your file like it is in the same folder with your Main class. You should be using the correct relative path if you want to access your file.